# You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on in React.js

Tags: reactjs, url, redirect, caching, routes

I am getting this warning even I am not on that page.
for example, when I enter to *profile/index* it shows me than I am in *feed* page.
[image]

This is my router settings

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/profile/index" component={ProfilePage} />
      <Route exact path="/feed" component={FeedPage} />
      <Redirect to="/feed?time=" + Date.now() />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

It's same when I remove *exact* keyword.

I am adding Date.now() at end of redirection target to avoid js file not loading because of cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the components:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom

...

export default withRouter(comonentName)
```

You can also try using `this.props.history.push` instead and see if it works the way you want. You can pass props like this:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/pathname',
  state: { key: value, key2: value2 }
})
```